# Small Caps Kerning for "Va" in Linux Libtertine (XeTeX)

Tags: fonts, xetex, small-caps, libertine, kerning

Has anyone else noticed this kerning error in Linux Libertine small caps...?

[image: Kerning combo "Va" (and "Wa") error in Linux Libertine.]

What are the (1) permanent solution & (2) quick local fix?

Pretty important initial combo.

Here's the code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}

% BEGIN

\begin{document} % ==============================================================

Vacillate Vaccine Vapour Vanish Va...

\textit{Vacillate Vaccine Vapour Vanish Va...}

\textsf{Vacillate Vaccine Vapour Vanish Va...}

\texttt{Vacillate Vaccine Vapour Vanish Va...}

\textbf{Vacillate Vaccine Vapour Vanish Va...}

\vspace{3ex}

\textsc{Vacillate Waccine Vapour Vanish Va...}

\textsc{\textsf{Vacillate Vaccine Vapour Vanish Va...}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiling your document with `lualatex` (without `xltxtra`) gives good kerning pairs.

Comment: Also good kerning pairs for the examples using \usepackage{libertine} and [pdf]latex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After discussing this on HarfBuzz [mailing list](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/harfbuzz/2013-August/003470.html), it appears to be a bug in the latest version of Linux Libertine. The proper action here is to notify the font developers and point them to that discussion, a short term “fix” is to downgrade to version 5.1.3 of the font.

Based on that, I believe it is a LuaTeX font loader bug to apply the kerning here, as it does not confirm with the OpenType specification (or its defacto reference implementation; Uniscribe).

Comment: I'm confused by your reference to a *LuaTeX* font loader bug -- the problem described by the OP occurs if the document is compiled with Xe(La)TeX; the "VA" kerning problem does *not* arise if the document is compiled under Lua(La)TeX.

Comment: @Mico: right. The LuaTeX issue is also a bug, since it applies kerning incorrectly (albeit with a an accidentally correct result.)

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thanks for providing this clarification. I hadn't realized that two mutually-offsetting errors in the LuaTeX font loader were in play. :-)

Comment: @Mico: As Alan said, though applying the kerning here gives the desired result, it violates the spec and thus can potentially break other fonts that might depend on this behaviour (unlikely but not impossible).

Comment: [Reported](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/074392.html). For the time being the bug can be avoided by using base mode.

Comment: Sorry, "base mode"?

Comment: @commonhare: `Renderer=Base` option in `fontspec` font commands.

Comment: @Khaled: Very specific conflict when using Lao type, which for the moment requires `Renderer=AAT`...just noting here for completeness, as it will only effect people (1) using Libertine AND (2) writing in English & Lao AND (3) using a Mac.

Comment: `AAT` is XeTeX-only option, while `Basic` (not `Base`, sorry) is a LuaTeX-only option, so I don’t understand your conflict remark (besides you only need `AAT` if you are using an AAT Lao font, if you are using an OpenType font, you don’t nee it).

Comment: @Khaled: I see.  Using XeTeX & AAT Lao font here.